# Patterns for handling sensitive data in REST API

Tags: spring, rest, api, security, spring-boot

I have a REST resource with GETs "Masked" sensitive data e.g. This API is consumed by application UI

GET /api/customer

```
{
"Name":"John"
"AccountNumber" :"XXXXX123"
}
```

This customer api in turn calls System of Records via another REST API. The system of records REST call is very expensive and supports very low TPS.  So we cannot use it frequently
When the customer does an action, the account number has to be passed to another resource
POST /api/transactions

```
Input
{
  "AccountNumber":"XXXXX123"....
}

Output
{
  "transaction":"something"....
}
```

The System of records wouldn't understand the masked AccountNumber. So The options that I could think of are-

- Set the unmasked account in server session and pass a key and masked account to the front end for customer API. The front end will pass the key  while calling  transaction API
- Use Server cache instead of server session
- Encrypt the account number using customer Identifier Key and SALT(like customer attributes that is injected in each request by reverse proxy) pass the encrypted account number to the front end. On customer action, the frontend will pass the encrypted account number to the backend. The backend will decrypt the string and extract the account number and customer identifier and match customer identifier with the one injected by the reverse proxy.

Option 1 and 2 are definitely poor design. I am leaning towards Option 3.

What is the well-established pattern for such requirements?